# Проблема в discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

Ошибка в последней строке, я хочу запустить проигрыватель, но выдается ошибка которую можно увидеть в самом низу, помогите с написанием этого кода, и пожалуйста поймите в чем ошибка. Код:

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.connect(reconnect=False)
            vc.play(source)
```

Ошибка:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: всё просто, сейчас `vc` у вас это `воис канал`(то есть объект голосового канала), а должен быть `voice_client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ (благодаря комментарию [@RAINGM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1353173/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-discord-py/1353762#comment2399976_1353173)): надо искать `voice_client`, а не `voice_channel`.